# HTML block element moves (changes margins) upon refresh

Tags: html, css, margin, page-refresh

I have two block elements inside an inline-block div, one of which is a vertical line as shown in the picture  [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwwU7.png)

Here's the code for reference

```css
.corner:before {
  display: block;
  width: 1px;
  min-height: 7vw;
  background: black;
  content: '';
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="corner" style="display: inline-block;">

  <h3 style="font-family: Italianno; 
                   writing-mode: vertical-rl; 
                   transform: rotate(180deg);
                   font-size: 3vw;
                   letter-spacing: 0.15em;
                   ">
    Sorority
  </h3>
</div>
```

However, upon page refresh the line dis-aligns itself and looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RURb3.png)

The line only realigns itself upon resizing the page or upon calling an `alert`. I've tried  calling windows.focus() upon page loading, but still no dice.

What's the problem here?

EDIT: The bug does NOT appear on Google Chrome, but only on FireFox

Comment: Everything seems to to be working fine for me. You just have an error after your content property. There's an equal sign that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Unable to reproduce the issue you describe which leads me to believe the problem is caused by either other css or other html elements rather than the code above - however `content: ''; =` is incorrect! Remove the `=`

Comment: Are you sure ? Because running a code snippet on this page shows this problem. EDIT: The bug does NOT appear on google chrome, but on firefox.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>
            design
        </title>
        <style>
    .corner{
    font-family: Italianno; 
    writing-mode: vertical-rl; 
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    font-size: 3vw;
    letter-spacing: 0.15em;
    position:relative;
    }
    .corner:before{
    display:block;
    width: 1px;
    min-height: 7vh;
    background: black;
    content: '';
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-7vh;
    left:50%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>

  <div style="display: inline-block; margin-top:7vh;" >
    <h3  class='corner'>
      Sorority
    </h3>
  </div>
```

Try using positions relative and absolute. This will prevent the line from re-aligning itself at different view-ports.

I'll highlight some issues to consider here:
Consider using `'em'` and `'px'` for font-size and height/width measurement. Also, in `min-height: 7vw;` in your code, it should be `min-height: 7vh;`(view-port height).
The problem with using`vh` and `vw` is that it'll end up stretching your elements at different view ports. But if you change everything to `px` or 'em' you'll get a well defined staged content. If you'd like to resolve the issue of responsive view port while using 'em or px', make the div container holding the element responsive using '%';

Comment: Noted! So I set the font-size attribute of the div container or the element itself ?